# Joomla! and VirtueMart import users

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a list of about 700 users with information that i'd like to import into virtuemart but really don't see a way how. I can import them to joomla but that doesnt register with the virtuemart user table. Is there a way to import a list of users and information directly into virtuemart? I found a tool such as CSVI but you can only import items like user details etc. which isnt users. HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I found one forum with what appears to be a solution. Source: http://pc-prog.eu/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4

> DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL COMPONENT MODULE - USERPORT
>   http://extensions.joomla.org/component/option,com_mtree/task,writereview/link_id,5430/Itemid,35/
>
> !!! If there is a problem to install direct on the web !!!
>
> 1) Install on localhost "c:\xampp...
>
> 2) Copy files
>   "c:\xampp\htdocs\your_project\administrator\components\com_userport"
>   - via ftp (Tip: check files with current date)
>
> 3) Update Joomla db - table jos_components (TP: see attached XLS,
>   sheet "1_InsertInto_jos_components"
>
> - IMPORT USERS INTO JOOMLA
>
> Administrator / Components / userport
>
> 1) Set parameters (e.g. fields separator: vertical bar) !!! e-mail
>   adresses must be Unique
>
> 2) Copy / Paste users – and run “Add and Update”
>
> 3) Check VirtueMart - Users tables: t: _users, _vm_user_info,
>   _vm_shopper_vendor_xref (via _vm_shopper_group)
>
> *main user table: jos_users.
>   *shopper groups table: jos_vm_shopper_group (the shopper_group_id column).
>   *glue that holds them together: the jos_vm_shopper_vendor_xref.
>
> ???: Main problem: How to generate "user_info_id" From the source
>   code, this field is: md5( uniqid(_VIRTUEMART_SECRET ))
>
> - ADD USERS INTO VM - “STEP BY STEP – TO DO!”
>
> 0)Update db - tbl "Components" (when userport must be installed on
>   localhost ) see attached XLS, sheet "1_InsertInto_jos_components"
>
> 1) Prepare user list in Excel, !!! – check, if e-mail addresses are
>   unique !!! – password should be min 5 characters
>
> 2) Joomla Administrator / Components / userport / Add&Update  !!! Set
>   parameters first from sheet "2_CustomerList ", clm "CSV_list" /
>   Copy-Paste data into userport
>
> 3) Joomla Administrator / Components / virtuemart/ Users  (only Check
>   if you can see new users)
>
> 4) MS Access: select new user only (… if you have connected MySQL db
>   via MySQL ODBC) SELECT jos_users.* FROM jos_users LEFT JOIN
>   jos_vm_user_info ON jos_users.id = jos_vm_user_info.user_id WHERE
>   (((jos_vm_user_info.user_id) Is Null));
>
> 5) Copy-Paste into MS-Excel into sheet "3_NewUsers" clm’s "B:N" /
>   Copy-Paste
>
> 6) Copy-Paste from Excel into h t t p://yourproject.com/phpmyadmin ...
>   clm "vm_shopper_vendor_xref" / and run
>
> 7) Copy-Paste from Excel into h t t p://yourproject.com/phpmyadmin ...
>   clm "vm_user_info" / and run